# Xcode 7.2 Syntax Highlighting flickering in Swift Files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, editor

When I write anything in a Swift file in Xcode 7, every time I enter an letter, a space or delete anything, the syntax highlighted words in the line go white and then back to their original color. I recorded a gif, better explaining, what I mean:

[image: Bug]

This first appeared, after I installed [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io) and a few plugins. After I noticed the bug, I removed all plugins and then Alcatraz, but the bug still existed. I also tried to delete the `Derived Data` folder as suggested in a few posts, but it didn't help.

I also created a new project, but the error occurred there too. Downloading Xcode 7.3 beta, didn't help too.

Is anyone having the same issue or knows, how to fix it? It's really annoying.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall XCode?

Comment: I restored an older version of the .app file and executed it from the desktop. Same bug.

Or is there anything else, I should delete affecting Xcode?

Comment: I just created a new user in OS X and started Xcode. The bug exists there too.

Comment: So I will change to default theme now and report the bug to Apple, hoping it will be fixed in the future. Since anyone of you has this error, it must be there before and I just not noticed it. Thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: this happens to me often as well. Except every bit of code in the entire file I am working in will go white and sometimes it lasts up to a minute. I have not filed a bug report yet but I plan to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce this bug and figured I have the same issue. Since I don't use such high contrast colours for syntax highlighting, I didn't notice until now.

I presume it's not a bug only you are experiencing, so maybe you could try to file a bug report to Apple [here](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a result of the constant syntax scanning done by the text engine as you type.

If you find the effect objectionable, switch (for now) to the Default theme (or some other theme that has a white background) instead of the black background you're currently using; it is not noticeable there.

Comment: That might be, but I'm pretty sure, this didn't exist before... I used the Dusk theme before and didn't notice it.

Comment: Okay, I'll take out the claim that it's not a bug, because if this is new behavior it could be an unintended consequence of some change in the parser.